# How To Ignore Collision Between Two Objects On The Call Of A Script In Unity3D?

Tags: collision, unity-game-engine

Basically, what I want to do is have two objects (fpscontroller and a wall) that collide like normal. But, once a script runs, they won't collide anymore.
So, how do I make that script that makes the two objects ignore collision with each other? I've tried looking this up, and what I got was Physics.IgnoreCollision, but the documentation on that confused me. And when I tried putting it in and replacing their variables with my variables, I got a bunch of errors.
So, please help.

Comment: I have an idea for your solution, but can you post some of your code. Also,  do you currently have colliders attached to your objects? Either way, look into the detection of collisions using colliders. [Unity Coliders](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)

Comment: Well, I don't really have any code, I want to know how to make the code to do what I want it to do. And, yea, I have colliders attached to both objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i would go about doing this is through layers.

In unity, a convenient way to ignore physics collision between objects is through setting the object to be ignored to a layer which your player object will always ignore.

**So, to go about setting this up imagine the following:**

***fpscontroller***'s layer is set to "player" (a layer i have created and named such).

***wall***'s layer is initially always set to "wall" (once again a layer i have created)

***Additionally***, I create a layer that i call "IgnorePlayerCollisions"

Now i go to: Edit > Project Settings > Physics
Here i can check the box which will turn off collisions between my ***player*** and ***IgnorePlayerCollisions*** layers.

**Now, at runtime i run my script which says:**

Change Wall Layer to "IgnorePlayerCollisions". Voila, my player now ignores all collisions with this layer.

Code Examples: (You don't need these all):

```
// Function to Change a GameObject Layer to the Ignore Layer
public void ChangeGameObjectLayerToIgnore(GameObject go) {
    go.layer = [Index of Ignore Layer];
}

// Function to Change "This" GameObjects layer to any other layer
public void ChangeThisGameObjectLayer(int layerIndex) {
    this.gameObject.layer = layerIndex;
}

// Change a GameObject layer to another layer
public void ChangeGameObjectLayer(GameObject go, int layerIndex) {
    go.layer = layerIndex;
}
```

**How?**

Place a C# function into a script and attach it to either your desired gameobject. In your case, i may attach it my Player GameObject since it seems like you may want to disable object throughout the game based on specific trigger or something. It really depends on how you plan to trigger the function.

Let me know if this makes sense or not. If not, i can attempt to make it more legible.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: What am I supposed to substitute in with the code and where? Do you think you could give me an example code, with the names that you gave in the post? Thanks.

Comment: Made some changes to my answer for more clarification. How are you trying to trigger the layer change?

Comment: I just want to have a timer, then have the code to make the objects not collide run. Also, I'm sorry, but I still don't get what to substitute in for the code.

Comment: Not problem, no need to say sorry. Questions are a good thing :D. What don't you understand about the above code (that is code which will work if you set it up correctly)? Do you have the time working in code? If so, you can add one of the above functions to your script and when your time hits "0" you can call one of the above functions.

Comment: I know this is a very noob question, but how do I call the function? Also, am I supposed to add the name of the variable for my GameObject? Because I have the code "public GameObject thing;" and the wall set as thing. But whenever I replace the GameObject in "(GameObject go)" I get errors. So, what do I do? Oh, I'm using the first script, by the way.

Comment: @user3583094 could you post the script you currently have hacked together? I can give you some advice and make some edits to make it more understandable if you give me some code. Otherwise, i'll end up giving you the solution...and that wouldn't be fun would it? **:P**

Comment: I actually figured out how to switch layers just earlier, but thanks for trying to help. Even if I figured it out myself just now, it wouldn't have ever occurred to me to use layers! So, thanks!

Comment: @user3583094 glad to hear it! Keep up the being awesome :D